# Fetching datetime from float in Python

Tags: python, datetime

How does one get a `datetime` from a `float` in Python?

For e.g, I have a float such as 43111.0 and I want to get the `datetime` for this.

Comment: What is 43111.0 supposed to be? Is that some weird non-standard timestamp?

Comment: 43111 is the number format for the date 11 January 2018.

Comment: Do you have a specification or something for this?

Comment: @Jacob usually a float as a date is days since the epoch.  Everything to left of the decimal is usually seconds or miliseconds.

Answer (score 63):

Looks like an Excel datetime format, called [serial date](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm). Quick and dirty way to convert it:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> serial = 43111.0
>>> seconds = (serial - 25569) * 86400.0
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)
datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 11, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.fromtimestamp(*your_timestamp_here*).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 13):

```
import datetime, time

print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())
print datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(43111.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but 43111.0 is not the timestamp,it is the flaot number format for the date 11 January 2018.

Answer (score 8):

So, with a little math:

If 43111 is 11 January 2018, then 0 is 30th December 1899.
Python has [`datetime.date.fromordinal()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromordinal)

> Return the date corresponding to the proleptic Gregorian ordinal,
>   where January 1 of year 1 has ordinal 1. ValueError is raised unless 1
>   <= ordinal <= date.max.toordinal(). For any date d,
>   date.fromordinal(d.toordinal()) == d.

If you use that with an offset, you have:

```
>>> dateoffset = 693594
>>> datetime.date.fromordinal(dateoffset + 43111)
datetime.date(2018, 1, 11)
```

Hope that helps, even if it does not work for floats.

Comment: One has to handle fractional part separately if ordinals are used:(

Answer (score 0):

## Here is another way

```
from pyxlsb import convert_date
convert_date(value)
```

You can use

```
format(convert_date(value), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

if you want to format it.

Comment: from a .xlsb no less, tyvm