# convert date to number python

Tags: python, matlab, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetching datetime from float and vice versa in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706231/fetching-datetime-from-float-and-vice-versa-in-python)

Like many people I switched from `Matlab` to `Python`.  `Matlab` represents each date as a number.  (`Integers` being days since `00-00-0000`, and fractions being time in the day).  I believe that `python` does the same except off a different start date `0-0-0001`

I have been playing around with `datetime`, but cant seem to get away from `datetime` objects and `timedeltas`.  I am sure this is dead simple, but how do I work with plain old numbers (floats)?

perhaps as a bit of context:

i bring in a date and time stamp and concatenate them to make one time value:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_object1 = datetime.strptime(date[1][0] + ' ' + date[1][1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date_object2 = datetime.strptime(date[2][0] + ' ' + date[2][1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: I guess it depends on what kind of date operations you want to do. If you're used to doing mathematical operations, then that kind of thing doesn't really work well with dates.. there's so many variables which proper date objects will handle for you, so maybe it's worth thinking that through first. Just a thought!

Comment: thanks NPE.  That is similar, except i want to go the other way (datetime to float)

Comment: danp, maybe that is the way to go.  I was looking at moving this into javascript so that I can play around with d3.js on it. but maybe I am too stuck in old Matlab ways

Comment: related: [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this out:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

t = datetime.now()
t1 = t.timetuple()

print time.mktime(t1)
```

It prints out a decimal representation of your date.

Comment: thanks ATOzTOA, this seems to work more effectively

Comment: And how will u get the actual date back from this?

Comment: @user2601010 datetime should have a function which takes integer argument

Answer (score 2):

The [datetime](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) class provides two methods, [datetime.timestamp()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) that gives you a `float` and  [datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp//docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) that does the reverse conversion. To get the timestamp corresponding to the current time you have the [time.time()](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html#time.time) function.

Note that POSIX epoch is 1970-01-01.

Comment: datetime.fromtimestamp(100.1) (out) datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 2, 1, 40, 100000)

Comment: Its worth pointing out that this only works in Python>=3.3.