# How to convert a Float value to date in actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, date, actionscript, floating-point

I am using as3xlsx reader to read the excel data and if it is date format,i am getting a floating point value like 41520.2916666667 which is actually 03-Sep-2013, in that case I need to convert the float value to date object in flex/as3. Is there any method to convert float to date in as3? I tried time stamp to date but it is not correct.

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got a quick solution from some links and updating here.. the issues are due Excel dates, those are really a timestamp with different starting point

```
 protected function excelFloatToDate(floatVal:Number):Date{
                var seconds:Number=(floatVal - 25569) * 86400.0;
                return new Date(seconds*1000);
            }
```

This method will return the correct date and time from the float value got from excel file.
reference links:- [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706231/fetching-datetime-from-float-and-vice-versa-in-python) and 
[excel date time details](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm)

Comment: Good find! Note it's perfectly acceptable to accept your own answer and close this question.

Comment: This has some limitation that it cannot read date before 1970 something like that(mentioned in the link that i have mentioned in the answer). If some better solution someone can provide that will be helpful.