# max of two dates comes in a totally different format

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have 2 columns with dates in them, i want to create a 3rd column with the max of these 2 dates:

```
df['xxx_MaxSettDate'][0]
Out[186]: Timestamp('2017-01-20 00:00:00')
df['yyy_MaxSettDate'][0]
Out[166]: NaT
```

here is my max function:

```
 df['MaxSettDate']=df[['xxx_MaxSettDate','yyy_MaxSettDate']].max(axis=1)
```

output:

```
df['MaxSettDate'][0]
Out[187]: 1.4848704e+18
```

I want to be able to do operation on this date, such as remove all dates which are lower than 1m

so I do this:

```
onemonthdate = date.today() + timedelta(30)
df = df[(df['MaxSettDate']>onemonthdate)]
```

This results in the error:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: float() > datetime.date()
```

Thoughts on how I could achieve this pls? I am geting very confused over all the solutions provided.. you could also just point me to something which I could read and understand the whole dates paradigm in python better.. thanks vm!

Comment: The datatype of `df['MaxSettDate']` and `onemonthdate` differs, thus the `TypeError`. Convert either one of the same type before doing the logical operation `>`.

Comment: Indeed what I am trying to understand.. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, you either search for either 'Convert float to datetime python' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706231/fetching-datetime-from-float-and-vice-versa-in-python or 'Convert datetime to float python' which should match what the float format of pandas produces.

Comment: perfect! thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

you can convert your `MaxSettDate` column to datetime first:

```
df['MaxSettDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['MaxSettDate'])
```

Demo:

```
In [41]: pd.to_datetime(1.4848704e+18)
Out[41]: Timestamp('2017-01-20 00:00:00')
```

OLD amswer:

I would use pandas Timedelta for that:

```
df = df[df['MaxSettDate'] > pd.datetime.now() + pd.Timedelta('30 days')]
```

Comment: Thanks! This would indeed be the tactical solution here.. Will apply that for now. However if I were to change the format itself, how would that go?

Comment: @spiff, can you post an output of: `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: `type(df[xxx_MaxSettDate'][0])
Out[194]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp`

`type(df['MaxSettDate'][12])
Out[199]: numpy.float64`

Comment: @spiff, well, what about the `df.dtypes`? You have to make sure that all values in your `xxx_MaxSettDate`, `yyy_MaxSettDate` columns are of datetime dtype

Comment: here it is:
`xxx_MaxSettDate         datetime64[ns]
yyy_MaxSettDate      datetime64[ns]
MaxSettDate                    float64`

Comment: so just by doing the max operation on datetime[ns] objects, the MaxSettDate column is converting to float64

Comment: got your updated answer! such a basic error...thanks vm!