# Scala Spark : Convert Double Column to Date Time Column in dataframe

Tags: scala, date, apache-spark

I am trying to write code to convert date-time columns date and last_updated_date which are actually unix times cast as doubles into "mm-dd-yyyy" format for display. How do I do this ?

```
import org.joda.time._
import scala.tools._
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat._
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{unix_timestamp, to_date}
root
 |-- date: double (nullable = false)
 |-- last_updated_date: double (nullable = false)
 |-- Percent_Used: double (nullable = false)

+------------+---------------------+------------+
|        date|    last_updated_date|Percent_Used|
+------------+---------------------+------------+
| 1.453923E12|        1.47080394E12| 1.948327124|
|1.4539233E12|        1.47080394E12| 2.019636442|
|1.4539236E12|        1.47080394E12| 1.995299371|
+------------+---------------------+------------+
```

Comment: Did you figure it out? If so can you help me with the answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast to timestamp:

```
df.select(col("date").cast("timestamp"));
```

Comment: Hmm i think there is some issue with this since date is "long" and that is causing the dates to go out of whack when doing this directly

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a timestamp using [`from_unixtime`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@from_unixtime(ut:org.apache.spark.sql.Column):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```
df.select(from_unixtime("date").as("date"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fetching datetime from float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706231/fetching-datetime-from-float-in-python)

This answer works for me give a try actually its a seconds calculation

> > > `import datetime
> > >       serial = 43822.59722222222
> > >       seconds = (serial - 25569) * 86400.0
> > >       print(datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds))`

[Convert excel timestamp double value into datetime or timestamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcFuy.png)