# Iterate through a Pandas DataFrame of Float time stamps and convert to date time

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, pandas, datetime-format

I have a Pandas Dataframe with 2000+ rows with date in float format as below:

`42704.99686342593` representing datetime value of `(2016, 11, 30, 23, 55, 29)`

What I want to do is iterate each row in the dataframe and convert the float to the correct datetime format ideally `d/m/Y H/M/S` and save this to a new dataframe.

Using Python 2.7.

I couldn't find any duplicate questions and was unable to solve the issue with solutions to similar questions so any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Include df.head() in your question.

Comment: How does 42704 equal Nov 11, 2016?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you use `serial date` what is [`Excel`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6706231/2901002) format.

The simpliest is substract `25569` and use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) with parameter `unit='d'`:

```
df =  pd.DataFrame({'date':[42704.99686342593,42704.99686342593]})
print (df)
           date
0  42704.996863
1  42704.996863

print (pd.to_datetime(df.date - 25569, unit='d'))

0   2016-11-30 23:55:28.963200
1   2016-11-30 23:55:28.963200
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Another solutions are substract `timedelta` or `offset`:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='d') - pd.to_timedelta('25569 Days'))
0   2016-11-30 23:55:28.963200
1   2016-11-30 23:55:28.963200
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df.date, unit='d') - pd.offsets.Day(25569))
0   2016-11-30 23:55:28.963200
1   2016-11-30 23:55:28.963200
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Thank you [Ted Petrou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464875/iterate-through-a-pandas-dataframe-of-float-time-stamps-and-convert-to-date-time/41465032?noredirect=1#comment70136420_41465032) for [link](http://excel.tips.net/T002051_Converting_UNIX_Date_Time_Stamps.html).

Comment: What's that subtraction and multiplication value?

Comment: @MYGz, i guess it's a result of a reverse ingeneering

Comment: I don't understand those, who have invented this `serial date` - it's a little bit perverse logic: `datetime.datetime(1970,1,1) - datetime.datetime(1899,12,30) == 25569`

Comment: It is bug, I try find it.

Comment: You should include a page of how you found out  about the excel time bug and how to convert it like this. http://excel.tips.net/T002051_Converting_UNIX_Date_Time_Stamps.html

Comment: Never mind. I see that you did include it already with a link

Comment: @jezrael -Thank you, it worked well.  I modified it slightly into a function which I then applied to the entire Dataframe but the answer you provided was at the core.