# convert double to time in python

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-aggregation, timefield

I have a TimeField() in my django models. I want to convert the sum of the record of this to hours.

Here's the actual code in my view:

```
hours_week_decimal = Timesheet.objects.filter(owner = request.user.pk, week = datetime.datetime.now().isocalendar()[1]).aggregate(total=Sum('working_hour')) # this method return a dict of decimal
total_hours_week = convertDecimalToHours(hours_week_decimal)
```

and the related function:

```
def convertDecimalToHours(times):
    total_time = 0
    for k, v in times.items():
        total_time += int(v)
    print("type: {} - value: {}".format(type(total_time), total_time))
```

This returned me:

```
 type: int - value: 166000
```

I have two hours:

```
 Monday (08:30) and Tuesday(08:30)
```

It must have returned me `"17:00"`

Hope you can help me in solving this problem :)

Comment: It would be much easier if you shared the example of `dict` in question.

Comment: Have you googled it?
Is it related to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6706329/10035556?

Comment: I don't know why you expect an output like `17:00` while your function output is  `print("type: {} - value: {}".format(type(total_time), total_time))`, so function `convertDecimalToHours(times)` does not produce what you want.

Comment: @Ssein it looks like the dict is having values like 083000 and 083000, for which sum is coming out as 166000 but he is expecting input as time 08:30 and 08:30 so output should be 170000 not 166000

Comment: Yes what you'r saying makes sense, however it's not that clear from what he just asked.

Comment: thanks for your answer, @zipa: 

In my database, i have a column of type "Time". The value's stored like this: 08:30:00.000000.

with my previous code, the times variables (passed in parameters) are like that:

{'total': Decimal('166000.000000')}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that 30m+30m = 60m that yes, is 1h, but you expected that the calculator was able to understand that you want 30+30 = 1h
So, in your case, you have to explicit convert 8:30 to 8.5

A fast but not graceful approach to extend your example with few lines can be:

- Convert your ints to strings.
- Cut out the hours (positions 0 and 1) and multiply for 60 to obtain minutes.
- Sum this result to the minutes (positions 2 and 3)

After doing this for every TimeField you have, sum all your times converted in minutes and then reconvert in hours.

In your example:

```
def convertDecimalToHours(times):
total_time = 0
for k, v in times.items():
    tmp_time = str(int(v))
    minutes = int(tmp_time[2:4]) + int(tmp_time[0:2])*60
    total_time += minutes / 60 # Now your 8:30 is 8.5
print("type: {} - value: {}".format(type(total_time), total_time))
```

Your output here will be 17.
I suggest you to use this as example to understand the concept, not as a packed solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer,

In my database, i have a column of type "Time". The value's stored like this: 08:30:00.000000.

with my previous code, the times variables (passed in parameters) are like that:

{'total': Decimal('166000.000000')}