# converting float number into datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a file that contains DateTime in float format
example `14052020175648.000000` I want to convert this into `14-05-2020` and leave the timestamp value.

input ==> `14052020175648.000000`

expected output ==> `14-05-2020`

Comment: did you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706231/fetching-datetime-from-float-in-python ?

Comment: It's not a timestamp 14052020175648.000000 -> 14/05/2020 17:56:48.000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp': ['14052020175648.000000']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'].astype(str).str[:8], format='%d%m%Y')
print(df)

# Output:
               Timestamp       Date
0  14052020175648.000000 2020-05-14
```

I used `astype(str)` in case where `Timestamp` is a float number and not a string, so it's not mandatory if your column already contains strings.

Answer (score 1):

This can solve your problem

```
from datetime import datetime
string = "14052020175648.000000"
yourDate = datetime.strptime(string[:8], '%d%m%Y').strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
print(yourDate)
```

Output:

```
14-05-2020
```